# Scrape class name at same tag

Tags: python

So i want to make an array with some class name
this is the code

```
<li class="li-bar-post bar188457" style="display:block;margin-bottom:20px;">...
<li class="li-bar-post bar188053" style="display:block;margin-bottom:20px;">...
<li class="li-bar-post bar187776" style="display:block;margin-bottom:20px;">...
<li class="li-bar-post bar187777" style="display:block;margin-bottom:20px;">...
<li class="li-bar-post bar187380" style="display:block;margin-bottom:20px;">...
```

i want the output to be :

`scraped = ["bar188457","bar188053","bar187776","bar187777","bar187380"]`

i know the basic scrape and how to do array append but to get that bar... name its pretty hard for me
this is my code

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')  
li = soup.li
print(li['class']
```

it just work for the first classname
what should i do

thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try? Where did you got stuck??

Comment: split the class at the space

Comment: stucked at how to find the right code to grab the classname

ive try .find .find_all .li['class'] its still cant grab the classname

Comment: I don't understand your problem. If I use `find_all("li")` then I can get all `li` and later I can run `for`-loop to get classes from all item, and it needs only to get class `bar...` and skip `'li-bar-post'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what is your problem.

`find_all("li")` gives all `li` and later you can use `for`-loop to work with every element separatelly - and you can get classes, and keep class which starts with `bar`

```
text = '''<li class="li-bar-post bar188457" style="display:block;margin-bottom:20px;">...
<li class="li-bar-post bar188053" style="display:block;margin-bottom:20px;">...
<li class="li-bar-post bar187776" style="display:block;margin-bottom:20px;">...
<li class="li-bar-post bar187777" style="display:block;margin-bottom:20px;">...
<li class="li-bar-post bar187380" style="display:block;margin-bottom:20px;">...'''

from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup

scraped = []

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')  

#all_li = soup.find_all('li')
all_li = soup.find_all('li', {"class": True})  # to make sure item has classes

for li in all_li:
    #print('li:', li.get('class'))
    for cls in li.get('class'):
        if cls.startswith('bar'):
            scraped.append(cls)
            
print('scraped:', scraped)
```

---

I use `{"class": True}` to make sure item will give list with classes (not `None`) but you can also use `.get('class', [])`.

---

**BTW:**

You can also write it as list comprehension but it can be less readable

```
scraped = [cls for li in all_li for cls in li.get('class') if cls.startswith('bar')]
```